# Why does the wizard high council tolerate witchcraft when women outnumbered men by 10:1?

Tags: magic

In an alternate world there exists a country surrounded by impassible mountains and vast ocean infested with carnivorous sea monsters, the technology is similar to the 14th century and everyone has a certain degree of affinity to magic. Due to the constant conflicts between province and villages, many men mostly young teenager who received little to no training in wizardry perished. Despite the differences in their belief systems all the people forbids women to join the war, at the time lady must be refined and remain virtue and played an important role to nurture the future pillars of state. The women hands must never be stained with blood as most will agree and offender shall be prosecuted by drowning or fed to the kraken.

However it is known that all girls unlocks their innate magical ability much earlier than boys and the wizard high council members are aware that a specific hormone produced in the mammary glands is responsible for allowing user to wield magic. (By the way all members are male because magic is associated with violence all the time despite what the actual statistics shown)

Eventually any women committing the taboo is guilty of witchcraft throughout history and usually face public execution. Despite the high council members do not recognize witchcraft why would they still tolerate the practice of witchcraft in secret?

Answer (score 5):

## Patriarchy!

But the patriarchy has a problem. They're so short of people that they can't teach all the kids the basics and still have enough manpower to hold up the town defences. Someone has to teach the kids, someone has to know when they're ready to actually start doing magic, and who better than their own mothers.

Each mother, knowing that magic is forbidden to them, still wants to give their children the best chance in life. The children also knowing that magic is forbidden to women would never betray their own mothers. So the cycle continues, boys taught basic fire starting, milk cooling, healing and household magics by their mothers, move on to the patriarchal combat magic as taught by a bunch of blinkered old men who don't want to see the truth in front of their eyes.